# primary key auto reset increment value

Tags: sql-server-2008, key

I have a question about creating a primary key for a table using two of its data elements along with an automatically incrementing value. 
 
I have a table that contains 
Dataset-a three letter acronym and 
DepositDate
I would like to create a primary key for this table that combines dataset and depositDate with an automatically incrementing value. 
I can create this column with a value that keeps growing larger, but what I would like is for it to reset with each new day.
For example, on 11/8/2013 for ACA, the first insert for the day would have an identifier of:
ACA-110813-01 
the second:
 ACA-110813-02 
and so on 
Then the first insert on 11/9/2013 would be: 
ACA0-110913-01

Is this possible in table creation or through any stored procedures or triggers?

I am using SQLServer 2008 

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found was to use a stored procedure to insert the data into my table.

I created a column in my target table (ledgers.deposits) called depositNum which is the value I will be incrementing.

```
CREATE TABLE [Ledgers].[Deposits]
(
[Dataset] [nvarchar](3), 
[DepositDate] [date], 
[Payer] [nvarchar](100), 
[CheckNum] [nvarchar](100), 
[CheckAmt] [decimal](18, 2),
[depositNum] [bigint], 
[depositId]  AS ((((((CONVERT([nvarchar],[Dataset],0)+'-')+    CONVERT([nvarchar],datepart(month,[DepositDate]),0))+CONVERT([nvarchar],datepart(day,[DepositDate]),0))+CONVERT([nvarchar],datepart(year,[DepositDate]),0))+'-')+CONVERT([nvarchar],[depositNum],0))))
```

I insert data with a stored procedure which will increment the depositNum based on the dataset and the day. Then that value is concatenated into the depositId column which I set as the primary key.
Here is the stored procedure that inserts the data and increments the depositNum.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Ledgers].[insertDeposit]
@dataset nvarchar(3),
@depositDate date, 
@payer nvarchar(100),
@checkNum nvarchar(100),
@depositAmt decimal(18,2)


AS

insert into Ledgers.Deposits 
values(
@dataset, 
@depositDate,
@payer, 
@checkNum, 
@depositAmt,
(
select ISNULL(max(depositNum+1), 1) 
from Ledgers.Deposits
where Dataset=@dataset and DepositDate=@depositDate
))
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Are you really going to use a `bigint` as the deposit number instead of an `int` or even a `smallint` or `tinyint`, i.e.: are you expecting to have more than *two billion* deposits?  Best practice in PK design is to keep PKs as narrow (as few bytes) as possible.

Comment: You might want to set the transaction isolation level to ensure that two clients running at the same time don't get the same number assigned.

Comment: You are right. Keeping that value low is the whole reason for the stored procedure! I have decided to go with smallint. I have also changed the isolation level to read committed. Thank you for your feedback edit *incomplete*